# Blade additive or dynamic yields

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

So I am working on a page that displays various informational cards and each card has its own javascript unique to the card.  I want to ensure that my javascript is loaded after jquery, which is loaded by every page, so it is at the bottom of the main template.  I attempted to create a second yield called "scripts" to load in any section named scripts that is loaded by that page. Here is a very stripped down example of what I am trying to do:

body.blade:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')

        {{-- jQuery --}}
        {{ HTML::script('/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') }}
        {{-- Other JS from various pages loaded in via blade after jquery.--}}
        @yield('scripts', '')
    </body>
</html>
```

cards.blade:

```
@extends('body')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    @include('cards.foo')
    @include('cards.bar')
    @include('cards.baz')
    @include('cards.fizz')
    @include('cards.buzz')
</div>
@stop
```

cards.foo.blade:

```
<div id="foo">
    <p> some info about foo </p>
</div>

@section('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        alert("foo");
    } );
</script>

@stop
```

cards.bar.blade:

```
<div id="bar">
    <p> something to do with bar </p>
</div>

@section('scripts')
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        alert("bar");
    } );
</script>

@stop
```

(etc..)

Final render:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="foo">
                <p> some info about foo </p>
            </div>
            <div id="bar">
                <p> something to do with bar </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src='/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function () {
                alert("foo");
            } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I want:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="foo">
                <p> some info about foo </p>
            </div>
            <div id="bar">
                <p> something to do with bar </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src='/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function () {
                alert("foo");
            } );
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready( function () {
                alert("bar");
            } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The cards are dynamic, so I don't know which ones might be loaded.  I don't think I should need to add a yield for every single card to the main template of the site.  The idea is that cards would me fairly modular to add since they are self-contained, but my current solution only loads in the javascript from whichever card is called first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do it in other way.

**body.blade.php** - unchanged

**cards.blade.php**

```
@extends('body')

@section('content')

<div class="container">
    @include('cards.foo')
    @include('cards.bar')
    @include('cards.baz')
    @include('cards.fizz')
    @include('cards.buzz')
</div>
@stop

@section('scripts')
    @include('cards.foo_js')
    @include('cards.bar_js')
    @include('cards.baz_js')
    @include('cards.fizz_js')
    @include('cards.buzz_js')
@stop
```

And now divide all files into 2 ones:

**cards/foo.blade.php**

```
<div id="foo">
    <p> some info about foo </p>
</div>
```

**cards/foo_js.blade.php**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        alert("foo");
    } );
</script>
```

Of course if in each card you use only document ready it doesn't make much sense to do it this way, you should merge document.ready to one and in each js file display only `alert("foo");` and in `body.blade.php` do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        @yield('content')

        {{-- jQuery --}}
        {{ HTML::script('/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') }}
        {{-- Other JS from various pages loaded in via blade after jquery.--}}

    <script>
        $(document).ready( function () {
            @yield('scripts', '')
        } );
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The document.ready was just an example, many of the cards have interactive js elements. I guess I was stuck thinking about pulling in the js directly to the body without realizing I could merge them all into one section first.  This works really well, thanks!